# What is a "default Python installation"?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, miniconda

Upon installing Anaconda / Miniconda, there is a prompt that reads:
[image: Anaconda installation]

Where the second tick box has something about "Register Anaconda3 as my default Python 3._"
The image says 3.8 but that's just because I couldn't find an image that said 3.9.

I'm wondering what exactly this does to my system and what exactly it means by "default Python 3.8". Having selected that option, it doesn't seem like anything on my path is edited, and in fact, calling py in my terminal doesn't default to this unless I actually specify that I want Anaconda in my path, so I'm really unsure as to how this links to any other programs like mentioned, such as PyCharm.

Also, is there a point to having both Anaconda's Python 3.9 installed and having the classic Python 3.9 from the Python website installed at the same time? It seems to me like Anaconda's Python 3.9 is simply a better and more versatile version of the classic Python 3.9, but I could be wrong and am unsure as I'm really new to this. As far as I can see, however, Anaconda gives users the ability to install any other version of Python through the command line and use their own environment manager, which seems to just be an upgraded version of pip if I'm not wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I would say... just go for it

Comment: can always roll back w/ uninstall if you notice any issues

Comment: personally I use `pyenv` instead of anocando for switching between multiple versions

Comment: @help The question was a little buried, my bad, there's a sentence that reads "I'm wondering what exactly this does to my system and what exactly it means by "default Python 3.8." I've reformatted my question. Also wondering about the last part, where I'm just wondering if there's even a reason to keep both on my computer (or whether I should just remove the others to reduce chance of confusion in the future).

Comment: @rv.kvetch It's more that I'm just wondering what it does, as I've gone through my computer and searched around after selecting that option but I still have no idea how it's affected my system // how other applications determine which Python is considered "default".

Comment: @amai I think it is not recommended but the use of the above option is that you can access anaconda i.e. that is starting  anaconda directly from your command prompt.

Comment: @help I understand the above option is not recommended, but what my question is about is the bottom option, as I'm wondering what it means by "Register Anaconda as default Python 3.8".

Comment: The use of "Register Anaconda as default Python 3.8" , u can uncheck this box if you are going to run different version of python i.e. python 3.8, 2.something, by checking this box u accept python 3.8 as default version for the anaconda and no other version can be used. @amai

Comment: If you want to have more detail of the download processes and options, you can check a YouTube video or go to the official website for help using : https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

Comment: @help I appreciate your effort to help very much, but that still doesn't answer the question I was trying to ask: what does that do internally to the system? I get why you should or shouldn't click it, but I don't get what it does. Even if I check that box, it still lets me use my system's Python installation if I specify the path to the python.exe. If I set my system's Python in the environment variables path, it will even default to the system's Python. How does clicking that button allow PyCharm, or other apps to know what the "default" Python is, internally?

Comment: I think you are trying to find out how does ide like Pycharm know the default path if I tick the box if so this link might help : https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/. If not can you please simplify your question for me. I myself don't have any idea ,its fun searching and learning your question's answer. @amai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses a registry to manage system configuration, including [entries determining what program will open files with a particular extension](https://superuser.com/q/266268). It seems to me that Anaconda is offering to create a registry entry that will associate `*.py` files with the **base** Python in your installation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!! From the post you've linked, I can see that html files open on the browser, pdfs on Adobe Reader or whatever PDF reader is downloaded, and so on. However, with .py files, as "opening" them, doesn't seem to run them, but rather open the file in an editor, so I'm a little bit confused.  Could you clarify what you mean by associate the files with the base Python, as I guess, they're not really opened as with .html files on the browser, but rather they just open to the editor, if you know what I mean. Either way, your answer has been quite helpful!!